# analyzing dump file with VS from a different pc

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dmp, procdump

I am trying to analyze a dump file generated in a testing environment pc , on my pc with VS.
When I create a dump file ( using procdump ) on my pc and open it in VS I can see my code in the threads window.
But when running the same binaries on a different machine and generating the dump file, VS is not showing me my functions in the 'threads' window.

- I am using .net 4
- My pc is Win8 64 and the Testsing Pc is WinXp 32

Comment: You are not using .NET 4.0.  The XP machine is.  The mismatch between the .NET install on your machine vs the XP machine is the problem.  XP is done and over with, you do not want to support it.  If they make you anyway then you'll need access to your own XP machine with the tools that you need.

Comment: I feared that is the problem, unfortunately I have to support xp. thanks.

Comment: @jacob either you build a Windows XP to be consistent, or you have to rely on a debugger such as WinDbg. WinDbg won't be easier in this case, as you will need to copy sos.dll and mscorwks.dll from that XP machine.

Comment: How can I do this with WinDbg ? I have a dump file of a hanging process, I have the matching pdb files and the source files. is it possible to view where the hanging code is ( assuming its somewhere in my code ) ?